# Java- Duda con números combinatorios

Tags: java, bucle-for, factorial

Soy estudiante de programación, en un ejercicio para clase me han pedido que haga una actividad sobre números combinatorios, he estado mirando tutoriales en youtube sobre como se realizaba, tampoco tiene ningún misterio, el problema es a la hora de plasmarlo en java, el resultado me da incorrecto y en teoria estoy haciendo los pasos, alguien me puede ayudar?

Este es mi código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n=0,m=0;

    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Escribe un numero:");
    m = lector.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Escribe otro numero:");
    n = lector.nextInt();
    if(m>n) {
    System.out.println("El resultado de la funcion combinatoria es: "+getCombinatorio(m,n));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("El valor de M debe ser mayor a N\nReinicia el programa");
    }
    lector.close();
}

public static int getCombinatorio(int m, int n){


    int operacion = 0, factorialm=m, factorialn=n, factorialmn=m-n;

    int mn = m-n;

    for (int i = m-1; i >=1; i--) {
        factorialm=factorialm*i;
    }


    for (int j = n-1; j >=1; j--) {
        factorialn=factorialn*j;
    }

    if(mn>2) {
        for (int k = mn-1; k >=1; k--) {
        factorialmn=factorialmn*k;
        }
    }
    else {
        factorialmn=mn;
    }

    operacion = factorialm/(factorialn*factorialmn);

    return operacion;
}
```

Se supone que la formula es (M N)= m!/n!(m-n)!  --> ! significa factorial.

He visto algunos ejemplos pero a mi no me sale este resultado, alguien me puede ayudar ?

Adjunto lo que me sale en consola:

```
Escribe un numero:
34
Escribe otro numero:
12
El resultado de la funcion combinatoria es: 0
```

Este debería ser el resultado según una calculadora online 548354040
http://es.onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/statistician/combination/

Una segunda prueba:

```
Escribe un numero:
50
Escribe otro numero:
34
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Act15.getCombinatorio(Act15.java:49)
    at Act15.main(Act15.java:16)
```

El resultado deberia ser : 4923689695575

```
La linea 49 es: operacion = factorialm/(factorialn*factorialmn);
La linea 16 es: System.out.println("El resultado de la funcion combinatoria es: "+getCombinatorio(m,n));
```

Otra prueba (curiosamente esta sale correcta, lo números pequeños como 4, 6 ,12 salen correctamente):

```
Escribe un numero:
4
Escribe otro numero:
2
El resultado de la funcion combinatoria es: 6
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado obtenido?

Comment: Hola! he adjuntado el resultado de consola abajo en mi pregunta

Comment: Como sugerencia para facilitar todo, la generación del factorial debería ser una función que reciba un número y entregue el factorial correspondiente :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recuerda que la división y la multiplicación tienen la misma jerarquía así que tienes que ponerle parentesis a la multiplicación para que se realice primero:

```
operacion = factorialm / (factorialn * factorialmn);
```

**EDIT**

En efecto al ingresar valores muy grandes obtienes resultados erroneos, es necesario cambiar tus variables a tipo **BigInteger** los cuales son capaces de manejar ese tipo de cantidades, a continuación te dejo como quedaria el metodo **getCombinatorio** para que funcione correctamente.

```
public static BigInteger getCombinatorio(int m, int n) {

    BigInteger operacion;
    BigInteger factorialm = BigInteger.valueOf(m);
    BigInteger factorialn = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    BigInteger factorialmn = BigInteger.valueOf(m - n);

    int mn = m - n;

    for (int i = m - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
        factorialm = factorialm.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    System.out.println("m " + factorialm);

    for (int j = n - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
        factorialn = factorialn.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(j));
    }
    System.out.println("n " + factorialn);
    if (mn > 2) {
        for (int k = mn - 1; k >= 1; k--) {
            factorialmn = factorialmn.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(k));
        }
    } else {
        factorialmn = BigInteger.valueOf(mn);
    }
    System.out.println("mn " + factorialmn);
    operacion = factorialm.divide(factorialn.multiply(factorialmn));

    return operacion;
}
```

Resultado:

```
Escribe un numero:
34
Escribe otro numero:
12
m 295232799039604140847618609643520000000
n 479001600
mn 1124000727777607680000
El resultado de la funcion es: 548354040
```

Comment: Esta es la solución :)

Comment: Hola fernando muchas gracias pero me salen mal los resultados en mi consola actualizo mi codigo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! ahora si que funciona no sabia que estaba haciendo mal, ya que en teoria estaba haciendo todos los pasos! PD: he probado a colocar double para no cambiar mucho mi codigo y tambien funciona, aunque me sale con comas.